# HTML is coming out as plaintext

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add some text to an element, however it is all coming out as plaintext, even when there is an HTML element included.

```
for (i = 0; i < restext.length; i++) {
    var p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = "<p>" + restext[i].innerHTML + "</p>";
    document.getElementById("registererrors").appendChild(p);
}
```

However with this, it prints out the  tag:

```
The name <em class="placeholder">name</em is already taken.
```

How do I make it so that it processes this tag too?

Comment: Without more details, one of the problems is that when you create the element, you don't need the p.innerHTML = "<p>".

Also, I notice that you have it say <em class="placeholder">name</em  and it doesn't have the closing >

Comment: We would need some more info. What is `restext`? What is the element `registererrors`? And what is value before appending your error messages?

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
p.innerHTML = "<p>" + restext[i].innerHTML + "</p>";
```

to

```
p.innerHTML = restext[i].innerHTML;
```

The problem is that after you create `p` element with `document.createElement` you add `<p></p>` inside of it. And inside of the inner `p` tag you insert other HTML code, which automatically gets escaped.

Comment: Adding additional `<p></p>` tags can surely not be the problem.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander are you sure that value in `restext[i].innerHTML` is correct? Could you possibly create a fiddle with your code?

Comment: The fiddle works when set as a string:

https://jsfiddle.net/bqgn8hbw/

But for some reason my actual code isn't producing this same result.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander then it has to be a problem with `restext` list. Can you check it's contents and confirm it's alright?

Comment: I mean the data gets printed out, so I'm not sure what it could be. It just doesn't parse the HTML properly.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander it seems to be something wrong with data inside `restext`, with tags specifically. Can you check that?